# Jquery POST com PHP não faz a consulta

Tags: jquery

Nunca fiz um script de Jquery que faz a consulta com PHP via POST.

O que consegui fazer é este:

```js
$('a.js-cd-panel-trigger').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var valor = $(this).attr('id');
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/fetch.php",
    data: {
      key: valor
    },
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {}
  })
});
```

Dei um alert no 'id' (variável 'valor') e está trazendo o id que vou fazer a consulta no PHP.
Se eu der um inspecionar elemento no Chrome e for em "Network", as funções que eu já customizei em outros projetos, eu consigo ver o retorno aqui.

Mas nesse caso, não está tendo retorno, parece que não está comunicando com o outro lado (do PHP).

Caso funcione, vou atribuir os valores em algumas tags.

Comment: Olá, você consegue nos dizer se no seu console do Browser apresenta algum erro ? como por exemplo: $ is not defined. Caso for isto. Você pode adicionar uma referencia da biblioteca Jquery para ter acesso a funcionalidade AJAX, você pode baixar ou apenas incluir o link do CDN no seu HTML onde o formulário se encontra. Link para download da biblioteca: https://jquery.com/download/
Link para documentação do Ajax: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ Fica mais fácil se você nos mandar o que está rolando no seu console. assim podemos ajudar com mais assertividade.

Comment: O retorno é guardado em `result`, dentro do callback `success`. Você pode usá-lo lá de dentro dessa função, que é chamada quando a requisição é completada com sucesso.

Comment: Entendi. Mas teria alguma forma de exibir o result no próprio navegador?